# Why do many express.js (web framework) examples attach express object to http object?

Tags: node.js, express

What's the meaning of passing `express` object to `http` object in this example?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Many examples do this. I don't quite know what it means.

Some other examples don't use `http` at all. Here's example from Express.js website (http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html), and it doesn't use `http` object:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World!')
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
})
```

Is there any difference at all? Does the second example still use `http` somehow? Or does it use express's own http server?

Comment: Did you check the docs for the `Server` call?

Comment: @DaveNewton I did, but it was way over my head to understand.

Comment: The doc for `http.Server()` does not describe what arguments it takes.  One could guess that maybe it's a synonym for `http.createServer()`, but that's just a guess.  I've found code for node modules to be very good and the documentation to be severely lacking.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `http.Server()` is a constructor (`new http.server()`), i.e. `http.createServer()`. However to get to your question, there isn't a large need to access the internal HTTP server from Express, because Express lets you do most of what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the `http` module's `Server` method is being called, which is effectively an alias for `createServer`. You can see the [relevant line here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L237). The argument is essentially a function which accepts parameters `request`, `response` as expected of a [requestListener](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request).

In the second example, Express already [requires `http`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L13) in its own module, so it is not necessary for the user to require it explicitly.

The main difference is that you are creating an instance of `http.Server` by yourself in the former, while Express [creates a server instance for you](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.listen) in the latter. Instantiating a server by yourself is necessary if you wish to use the `https` module instead of `http`.